# Accessing resource in project

Tags: java, file, io, resources, representation

```
src/author
    package1
        MainClass
    package2
        SomeClass
src/author/data
    resources1
        sometext.txt
        someimage.png
    resources2
        someobject.obj
```

With some structure like that, I want to represent `sometext.txt` as a `File` object in `MainClass`.

How should I do that to make it work with a jar export too?

Comment: Are you sure you need it as a File? Otherwise consider using it as a resource. In the classloader there are methods for this.

Comment: Hi iGoodie - your question would be better if you copied and pasted in your source code structure in text, rather than as an image. Images cannot be searched or indexed, or reformatted, for example.

Comment: I'm in need of some code chunk will be written in MainClass's EMPTY main method which will represent a new File object of sometext.txt file in src/author/data/resources1 folder. All these classes indicated in green are packaged like so; author.package1 and aouthor.package2 @VinceBowdren . This source will be exported as jar later. So it should work both ways

Answer (score 0):

If your only using a standard command line compiler, therefore not worrying over build specific root folders and such, then the path should be

> /data/sometext.txt

so basically if you would like to reference that file you would for example have to type

`"./data/sometext.txt"`

Comment: Nope not really. It won't find the path

Comment: The dot represent the folder where your main() function lives.

Comment: Still not working. Works only before export or after export.